# How to toggle a checkbox using a nearby element?

Tags: jquery, html

My goal is to make a checkbox menu that deselect all but the nearby `menu1` element when `.only` is clicked. To begin with, I was trying to actually *select* the corresponding element when `.only` is clicked.

Here is how I started: I am trying to select the the common parent between `.only` and `.menu1`, and then check it with `prop('checked', true)`, but what I have does not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/hjng93ro/

html and jquery

```
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="kayak.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class='boxmenu'>
<div class="row">
  <div class="right">
    <a class="only">only</a>
    <a class="price">$500</a>
  </div>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="first" class='menu1'/>
    FirstOption
  </span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="right">
    <a class="only">only</a>
    <a class="price">$700</a>
  </div>
  <span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cars" value="second" class='menu1'/>
    SecondOption
  </span>
</div>
</div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.only').on("click", function() {
   $(this).parents('.row').has('.menu1').first().prop('checked', true);
})
});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.right {
  float: right;
}
.only {
  display: none;
}
.price {
    display: inline;
}
.row:hover .only {
  display: inline;
}

.boxmenu {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: if we check first option you want to deselect the same after clicking on `.only` near $500 ?

Answer (score 1):

First uncheck all `.menu1`, then check the `.menu1` corresponding to the clicked `.only` like following.

```
$('.only').on("click", function() {
    $('.menu1').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.menu1').prop('checked', true);
})
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/hjng93ro/3/)

Comment: Thanks, would you mind adding a solution using `parents()`? I would like to understand what I was doing wrong apart from forgetting to uncheck everything.

Comment: It is very large to explain. You can go through the documentation of all methods used. The problem was with `has()` method. @Dambo

Answer (score 0):

You also need to unselect all checkboxes every time `.menu1` is clicked.
Also, instead of running

```
$('.menu1').prop('checked', false)
```

every time on click, its better to cache all `.menu1` elements beforehand.

```
var $textboxes = $('.boxmenu').find(':checkbox'),
    unselectAllCheckboxes = function() {
    $textboxes.prop('checked', false);
};
$('.only').on("click", function() {
    unselectAllCheckboxes();
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.menu1').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Here's the js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hjng93ro/7/